# xcode Assertion failed

Tags: xcode

On build of a project I am getting an Assertion failed pointing at this code. Any ideas why please? I have tried a cleaning, deleting derived data, closing xcode and more. Any help please.

```
unsigned int
FNVForCString(
    const char* s)
{
assert(s);

unsigned int hash = 2166136261;
int ch;
while (0 != (ch = *s++))
{
    hash *= 16777619;
    hash ^= ch;
}
return hash;
}
```

Just going to say it is failing on the assert(s); line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the language C? I've made that assumption here, though the answer varies very little if this is Objective-C.

The value you pass into the function is `NULL`

The `assert` is there to say "If the value `s` is `NULL`, fail at this point.

Comment: Gee I missed that, had a night of children madness. Thanks. found the error.